# Show Inno Setup children component as sibling and show check instead of square in checkbox

Tags: checkbox, inno-setup, hierarchy, pascalscript

I'm trying to have a children component to be shown as sibling. 
I'm making a installer for a Game which can have multiple versions of the game coexisting in the same installation folder.

Now I want to have the ability to install optional mods which require to have a specific version of the game installed (dependency). So when the user clicks on a mod, the required game gets selected, and if the game is deselected, all the mods get deselected. The code as is is working as expected and behaves as described before. It just gets a bit confusing for the user sometimes. For example if no mod is installed, in the game a square is shown instead of a check, and the hierarchy of the mods is unnecessary.

What I want to achieve:

1. I want to have `game_2` to show a **check** instead of a **square**.
2. To have `game_2\com_mods` as sibling of `game_2` and not as a children.

This is as far as I have arrived, I guess there is no easy way to have that effect. If I'm not wrong using the `[Code]` section it is possible to modify the UI but I don't know how to force the checkbox instead of the square and remove the padding of the children.

Here is my example code:

```
[Setup]
AppName=Demo
AppVersion=1.0
DefaultDirName=.

[Components]
Name: "game_1";    Description: "Game v1";  Types: full custom; Flags: checkablealone
Name: "game_2";    Description: "Game v2";  Types: full custom; Flags: checkablealone
Name: "game_2\com_mods";    Description: "Game Community Mods"; Types: full custom;  Flags: dontinheritcheck
Name: "game_2\com_mods\3rdmod1"; Description: "Mod 1"; Flags: exclusive
Name: "game_2\com_mods\3rdmod1"; Description: "Mod 2"; Flags: exclusive
Name: "game_2\com_mods\3rdmod1"; Description: "Mod 3"; Flags: exclusive
```

I hope somebody can help me or point me in the right direction to produce the desired effect.

Greetings and thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want this layout:

```
[Components]
Name: "game_1";    Description: "Game v1";  Types: full custom
Name: "game_2";    Description: "Game v2";  Types: full custom
Name: "com_mods";    Description: "Game Community Mods"; Types: full custom
Name: "com_mods\3rdmod1"; Description: "Mod 1"; Flags: exclusive
Name: "com_mods\3rdmod1"; Description: "Mod 2"; Flags: exclusive
Name: "com_mods\3rdmod1"; Description: "Mod 3"; Flags: exclusive
```

[image]

But you want to keep the behavior of your current layout.

Then you have to code the behavior in Pascal Scripting:

```pascal
[Code]

const
  Game2Index = 1;
  Game2ModsIndex = 2;

var
  Game2Checked: Boolean;

procedure ComponentsListClickCheck(Sender: TObject);
var
  ComponentsList: TNewCheckListBox;
begin
  ComponentsList := WizardForm.ComponentsList;

  // If Game 2 got unchecked
  if Game2Checked and
     (not ComponentsList.Checked[Game2Index]) then
  begin
    // uncheck the mods
    ComponentsList.Checked[Game2ModsIndex] := False;
  end; 

  // If Game 2 mods got checked, make sure Game 2 is checked too
  if ComponentsList.Checked[Game2ModsIndex] and
     (not ComponentsList.Checked[Game2Index]) then
  begin
    ComponentsList.Checked[Game2Index] := True;
  end; 

  Game2Checked := ComponentsList.Checked[Game2Index];
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  WizardForm.ComponentsList.OnClickCheck := @ComponentsListClickCheck;
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = wpSelectComponents then
  begin
    // Remember the initial state
    Game2Checked := WizardForm.ComponentsList.Checked[Game2Index];
  end;
end;
```

In Inno Setup 6, you can use [`WizardIsComponentSelected`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_wizardiscomponentselected) and [`WizardSelectComponents`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_wizardselectcomponents) instead of using indexes.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you a lot. It's just working perfectly. And thanks for the comments in the Code, I'm new to Pascal scripting in Inno Setup, so it helps me big deal with what's going on.