# Adding post-install radio option to do nothing when installer has finished

Tags: inno-setup

Some time back I had this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41370531/showing-run-tasks-as-radio-choices-instead-of-check-boxes). Some of that code is repeated here:

```pascal
procedure RebuildRunList;
var
  RunEntries: array of TRunEntry;
  I: Integer;
begin
  { Save run list ... }
  SetArrayLength(RunEntries, WizardForm.RunList.Items.Count);
  for I := 0 to WizardForm.RunList.Items.Count - 1 do
  begin
    RunEntries[I].Caption := WizardForm.RunList.ItemCaption[I];
    RunEntries[I].Checked := WizardForm.RunList.Checked[I];
    RunEntries[I].Object := WizardForm.RunList.ItemObject[I];
  end;

  { ... clear it ... }
  WizardForm.RunList.Items.Clear;

  { ... and re-create }
  for I := 0 to GetArrayLength(RunEntries) - 1 do
  begin
    { the first two entries are radio buttons }
    if (I = 0) or (I = 1) then
    begin
      WizardForm.RunList.AddRadioButton(
        RunEntries[I].Caption, '', 0, RunEntries[I].Checked, True, RunEntries[I].Object);
    end
      else
    begin
      WizardForm.RunList.AddCheckBox(
        RunEntries[I].Caption, '', 0, RunEntries[I].Checked, True, True, True,
        RunEntries[I].Object);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = wpFinished then
  begin
    { Only now is the RunList populated. }
    { Two entries are on 64-bit systems only. }
    if IsWin64 then RebuildRunList;
  end;
end;
```

I would like to know how I can make a enhancement to the radio choices. The drawback at the moment is that the user is forced to start one or the other application. I would like to add another radio option for simply closing down the installer. *Ideally it would use a Inno Setup supplied message so that I do not have to ask for translations.* (See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44988326/using-a-message-in-the-run-statement-of-a-innosetup-script)).

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to add a no-op entry to the `RunList`:

```
[Run]
...
Filename: "{cmd}"; Parameters: "/C exit"; Description: "Exit setup";  \
    Flags: nowait postinstall runasoriginaluser unchecked skipifsilent runhidden; \
    Check: IsWin64
```

And turn it to a radio button:

```pascal
    { the first three entries are radio buttons }
    if (I = 0) or (I = 1) or (I = 2) then
```

Comment: Thanks. Only clarification I would like to make here is that I had to make sure this new run entry was the **third** entry in the `[InstallRun]` section.

Comment: I meant `[Run]` :). I have added the other question BTW.

Comment: One thing I do notice here is that sometimes I see a flash of a MS-DOS window when the application is shutting down.

Comment: Should we add `runhidden` flag?

Comment: Yes, I've added `runhidden` to my answer.