# Using a standard Inno Setup message in the Run entry description

Tags: inno-setup

There is a related question for those who are interested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44987599/adding-post-install-radio-option-to-do-nothing-when-installer-has-finished/44988032#44988032). I was encouraged to ask one of the questions separately.

So I have this `[Run]` code:

```
Filename: "{cmd}"; Parameters: "/C exit"; Description: "Exit Setup";  \
    Flags: nowait postinstall runasoriginaluser unchecked skipifsilent; Check: IsWin64
```

It works well. It shows the following window at the end of the installation:

[image: InnoSetup install complete]

But the problem is that the wording **Exit Setup** is hard coded in English. Now, I have looked at the *default.isl* file and located:

```
ExitSetupTitle=Exit Setup
ClickFinish=Click Finish to exit Setup.
```

I don't know if I should be using either of these messages. It makes sense to me to use the **ClickFinish** because that is what the user will be doing.

But I can't work out how to use that message in the run statement.

## Update

I have modified the supplied answer to:

```
function GetClickFinishSetupMessage(Param: string): string;
var
  I: integer;
  S1: string;
  S2: string;
begin
  
  S1 := SetupMessage(msgClickFinish);
  I := Length(S1);
  S2 := Copy(S1, I-1, 1);
  if(S2 = '.') then
      S1 := Delete(S1, I-1, 1);
  end;

  result := S1;
end;
```

So I could remove the final period. But it will not compiled. It says there is a mismatch for the third parameter of `Delete`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`SetupMessage` support function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_setupmessage) from a [scripted constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants):

```
[Run]
Filename: ...; Description: {code:GetClickFinishSetupMessage}
```

```pascal
[Code]

function GetClickFinishSetupMessage(Param: string): string;
begin
  Result := SetupMessage(msgClickFinish);

  { Drop trailing dot, if any }
  if Copy(Result, Length(Result), 1) = '.' then
    SetLength(Result, Length(Result) - 1);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for your **excellent** help as usual! Side note: I wish some of the other translators would revise their installers (specifically **Albanian**).