# With Inno Set Up compiler, is it possible to mix both Checkbox and Radio button on the finalise page?

Tags: inno-setup

I want to have 2 check boxes and two radio buttons on the finalisation page of my install. I see from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35539827/how-to-allow-only-one-checked-box-in-run-section) that you can change all Check Boxes to Radio Buttons but how can I have a mix of both.

Comment: See [Showing run tasks as radio choices instead of check boxes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41370531/850848), where the code in @Andrew's anwer come from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used something like this:

```
type
    TRunEntry = record
        Caption: string;
        Checked: Boolean;
        Object: TObject;
    end;

procedure RebuildRunList;
var
    RunEntries: array of TRunEntry;
    I: Integer;
begin
    { Save run list ... }
    SetArrayLength(RunEntries, WizardForm.RunList.Items.Count);
    for I := 0 to WizardForm.RunList.Items.Count - 1 do
    begin
        RunEntries[I].Caption := WizardForm.RunList.ItemCaption[I];
        RunEntries[I].Checked := WizardForm.RunList.Checked[I];
        RunEntries[I].Object := WizardForm.RunList.ItemObject[I];
    end;

    { ... clear it ... }
    WizardForm.RunList.Items.Clear;

    { ... and re-create }
    for I := 0 to GetArrayLength(RunEntries) - 1 do
    begin
        { the first three entries are radio buttons }
        if (I = 0) or (I = 1) or (I = 2) then
        begin
            WizardForm.RunList.AddRadioButton(
                RunEntries[I].Caption, '', 0, RunEntries[I].Checked, True, RunEntries[I].Object);
        end
            else
        begin
            WizardForm.RunList.AddCheckBox(
                RunEntries[I].Caption, '', 0, RunEntries[I].Checked, True, True, True,
                RunEntries[I].Object);
        end;
    end;
end;
```

And it is called like this:

```
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
    if CurPageID = wpFinished then
    begin
        RebuildRunList;
    end;
end;
```

@MartinPrikryl might be able to find the original answer he provided me where this issue was discussed.

Comment: thanks for help  all going now