# Inno Setup Detect changed task/item in TasksList.OnClickCheck event

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I'm stuck on simple situation with `OnClickCheck` property. The problem is that I see a `Msgbox` every time I turn on `backup` task, but also (while it's switched on) `OnClickCheck`appeared on pressing `uninst` task too! Seems that `OnClickCheck` checks all clicks, but I need to check click only on the first task.

It is logical to add to "`WizardForm.TasksList.OnClickCheck`" exact number of task (`WizardForm.TasksList.OnClickCheck[0]`), but compiler doesn't agree with it.

```pascal
[Tasks]
Name: backup; Description: do backup
Name: uninst; Description: do not create uninstaller

[Code]

procedure TaskOnClick(Sender: TObject); 
begin
  if IsTaskSelected('backup') then 
  begin
    MsgBox('backup task has been checked.', mbInformation, MB_OK) 
  end;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  WizardForm.TasksList.OnClickCheck := @TaskOnClick;
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no way tell exactly what task (list item) was changed in the `OnClickCheck` event.

To tell which item was checked by the user, you can use the `ItemIndex` property. The user can check only the selected item.

Though if you have a task hierarchy, even unselected task can be toggled automatically by the installer due to a change in child/parent items. So to tell all changes, all you can do is to remember the previous state and compare it against the current state, when the `OnClickCheck` is called.

```pascal
var
  TasksState: array of TCheckBoxState;

procedure TasksClickCheck(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to WizardForm.TasksList.Items.Count - 1 do
  begin
    if TasksState[I] <> WizardForm.TasksList.State[I] then
    begin
      Log(Format('Task %d state changed from %d to %d',
                 [I, TasksState[I], WizardForm.TasksList.State[I]]));
      TasksState[I] := WizardForm.TasksList.State[I];
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  if CurPageID = wpSelectTasks then
  begin
    { Only now is the task list initialized (e.g. based on selected setup }
    { type and components). Remember what is the current/initial state. }
    SetArrayLength(TasksState, WizardForm.TasksList.Items.Count);
    for I := 0 to WizardForm.TasksList.Items.Count - 1 do
      TasksState[I] := WizardForm.TasksList.State[I];
  end;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  WizardForm.TasksList.OnClickCheck := @TasksClickCheck;
end;
```

---

Instead of using indexes, you can also use task names with use of [`WizardSelectedTasks`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_wizardselectedtasks) or [`WizardIsTaskSelected`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_wizardistaskselected). For an example, see [Inno Setup: how to auto select a component if another component is selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47431002/850848)

---

Also see:

- [Inno Setup ComponentsList OnClick event](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36989349/850848)
- [Inno Setup Uncheck a task when another task is checked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39297075/850848)
- [Inno Setup - Show children component as sibling and show check instead of square in checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32698111/850848)