# How can I set the "OnClickCheck" event for discrete checkbox from the "CheckBoxList" on "CreateInputOptionPage" page in InnoSetup?

Tags: inno-setup, checklistbox

How can attach events to discrete checkboxes on `CreateInputOptionPage` page?

My `CreateInputOptionPage` page is like this:

[image]

I have to implement the next cases:

1.`2` is `Checked` and `Disabled` by default

2.`1` is `Unchecked` by default

3.If `1` is `Checked` then `2` gets `Enabled` and can be then left `Unchecked` or changed to `Checked`

Comment: That looks like what checkbox levels are for. Did you consider using them instead?

Comment: To answer your literal question, see [Inno Setup Detect changed task/item in TasksList.OnClickCheck event](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42173752/850848).

Comment: I'm not sure how to use checkbox levels. Also I don't want my second checkbox to be shifted to the right.

Comment: OK, then you have the answer above.